# Emgu CV ColorConversion.RGB2GRAY/BGR2GRAY

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2015, emgucv

I'm working on my thesis currently on image processing this is my first time in image processing field and I am willing to learn more as this project progress. I'm quite stuck with the code:

```
CvInvoke.CvtColor(imgRgb, imgGray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Rgb2Gray)
```

I tried using this code but it only returns as black box in picturebox. I used this line immediately after CvtColor:

```
pictureBox1.Image = imgGray.ToBitmap();
```

I read the documentation on the RGB2GRAY and it states as a LUMA grayscale conversion and I really need this type of algorithm in my thesis. I would like to use the `Image<Gray, byte> gray_image = resizedImage.Convert<Gray, byte>()`, but I do not know what type of grayscale algorithm is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Neil,
While I do not know offhand the source for both EmguCV and OpenCV area freely available at their respective web sites. I would pull a copy of each and look. I just popped into the OpenCV documentation for 3.2 and found this:

**RGB ↔ GRAY

Transformations within RGB space like adding/removing the alpha channel, reversing the channel order, conversion to/from 16-bit RGB color (R5:G6:B5 or R5:G5:B5), as well as conversion to/from grayscale using:

RGB[A] to Gray:Y←0.299⋅R+0.587⋅G+0.114⋅B
and

Gray to RGB[A]:R←Y,G←Y,B←Y,A←max(ChannelRange)
The conversion from a RGB image to gray is done with:

cvtColor(src, bwsrc, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);**
[Find documentation here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html)

Doug

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your imgGray as Gray and not as Bgr

`Image<Gray, byte> imgGray`
and not
`Image<Bgr, byte> imgGray`

At least i am assuming this was your error becase i got the same black picture like you! But with this fix it worked.